# How to dynamically adjust figure size to fit subplots of fixed size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot grids of images of size `r x 5`, depending on a plot number of rows (r) varies. Right now I am setting figure size and matplotlib adjust subplots size according to figure size. I want the reverse -- figure size to be dynamically adjust given fixed subplot size.

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(len(lay), cols, figsize=(35.0, 20.00))

for r in range(len(lay)):
   layer = lay[r]
   for c in range(cols):
     img = layer[c]
     axs[r, c].imshow(im)

fig.show()
```

If I do not provide `figsize` then the size is too small.

I want each subplot image to be of size 150x150 pixels.
Or for the very least I want to figure how to set subplot size and then I can approximately adjust inches to pixels.

Thank you!